# Why can't I add a route with a different gateway?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I'm using Linux Centos 7/8.

- The main network is **92.168.0.1/24**
- The server has **192.168.0.70**

The server is connected to a switch that provides me access to a different subnet.

I would like to access a different subnet `10.50.0.0/24` using its gateway `10.50.0.254` but due to a requirement, I need to set the source IP as `172.16.0.10`

For that, I assign a second IP `172.16.0.10` to the eno0 interface.

Adding the IP isn't the problem: `ip addr add 172.16.0.10 dev eno0`

Nevertheless, adding the route `ip route add 10.50.0.0/24 via 10.50.0.254 src 172.16.0.10` returns `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`

What's strange is I don't see the ARP with tcpdump... How does it know the network is unreachable?!

#### Why? How can I add this route?

Comment: Why can’t you just assign 172.16.0.10 to lo0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does it know the network is unreachable?!

Because you don't yet have a direct route to 10.50.0.254. The system doesn't know which interface to use to reach the gateway itself.

You need to specify the gateway's *other* address – the one that's in your subnet. (A gateway will have multiple addresses, one from each network that it belongs to.)

- For example, if you are 192.168.0.70/24, and the gateway has 192.168.0.50/24 on its one interface and 10.50.0.254/24 on another, then your route would need to be:

  ```
  ip route add 10.50.0.0/24 via 192.168.0.50
  ```
- If the gateway is physically on your layer-2 network but for *some* reason doesn't have an address from your subnet (let's say if you have 2 different subnets sharing the same VLAN), then use whatever address it has, as long as *that* address is on your side.

  In this case, you'll need to specify the `onlink` flag to force Linux to accept the route, or alternatively add a device route for that address first. (Sometimes an address from *any* interface will work, but not all gateways respond to ARP requests for the "wrong" interface's IP addresses.)

  Let's say your ethernet concurrently has 192.168.0.0/24 and 192.168.5.0/24 for some reason, and you are 192.168.0.70 but want to use a gateway which is 192.168.5.50. This can be made to work:

  ```
  ip route add 10.50.0.0/24 via 192.168.5.50 onlink dev eno1
  ```

  Older kernels do not recognize the 'onlink' flag for IPv4 (it was originally added for IPv6) so they would need two routes, the first one a "direct" route declaring the gateway itself (or the whole subnet) as on-link:

  ```
  ip route add 192.168.5.50/32 dev eno1
  ip route add 10.50.0.0/24 via 192.168.5.50
  ```
- If the gateway is physically on your layer-2 network but for some reason doesn't have *any* IPv4 addresses on your side, it's possible to specify an IPv6 address as the gateway... so long as it gets resolved to the same layer-2 address:

  ```
  ip route add 10.50.0.0/24 via inet6 fe80::a1:b2c3 dev eno1
  ```
- Finally, **if the gateway *isn't* physically in your network... then there's no way to add a direct route through it,** because routes work by changing layer-2 addresses.

  You can only route through gateways which *are* physically in your network, and those gateways – not you – decide where to send the packet further. (A tunnel is sometimes an option to get around this restriction, but the remote gateway has to be explicitly set up to receive tunnelled packets.)

  *(There are "source routing" and "segment routing" systems which add exceptions to this rule but they aren't generally part of basic IP networks.)*

Comment: Reading your perfect answer, the mistake popped up... The gateway is `172.16.0.254`, not `10.1.94.254`. Both are physically on the switch (same VLAN, or non-vlan). It's very late here..

Comment: This makes sense, but you're likely to continue getting the error message because you added the extra IP address as a /32 -- so the OS still doesn't have any direct route that'd match the gateway. You should explicitly specify the prefix length using `ip addr add 172.16.0.10/24` or such. (Using 'onlink' will also work in this situation, but it is not the best approach.)

Comment: I didn't know the use of `onlink`, you answer is very good defining the different cases. Thank you!

Comment: Good catch, indeed, it was just a typo in the question, the mask was correctly specified in the cli.